# erro no finally com try cath

Tags: php, php-7

Estou tentando criar uma `classe` **statica** para `conexão` ao **mysql** com `PDO` mas está dando erro na linha do `finally`

```
<?php

  namespace CONEXAO;

  use PDO; 

  class Conexao {

      public static $conexao;

      private $host     = "localhost";   
      private $db       = "funeraria2";
      private $user     = "root";
      private $password = "mysql";

      private function __construct() {

          try {

             self::$conexao = new PDO('mysql:
                                  host="'.$this->host.'";
                                  dbname="'.$this->db.'", 
                                  "'.$this->user.'", 
                                  "'.$this->password.'"
                               ');

          } catch (Exception $e) {

        self::$conexao = NULL;

        return self::$conexao;

        echo $e->getMessage();

        exit;

          } finally {

             return self::$conexao;

          }
      }


      public function fechaConexao () {

          if (self::$conexao != null) {

              self::$conexao = null;

          }
      }   
  }
```

Estou usando o `Dreamweaver` como editor de `códigos` e ele me dá um erro na linha conforme imagem abaixo mas não consigo ver erro algum!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alteração:

```
<?php

  ini_set("display_errors",true);
  ini_set("display_startup_erros",true);
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);

  namespace CONEXAO;

  use PDO; 

  class Conexao {

      private static final $conexao;

      private static final $host     = "localhost";  
      private static final $dbname   = "dbname";
      private static final $user     = "user";
      private static final $password = "password";

      public function __construct() {}

      public function abreConexao() {

          try {

             self::$conexao = new PDO('mysql:
                                              host=self::$host;
                                              dbname=self::$dbname', 
                                              self::$user, 
                                              self::$password
                                     );

          } catch (Exception $e) {

            self::$conexao = NULL;

            echo $e->getMessage();

          } 

      }


      public function fechaConexao () {

          if (self::$conexao != null) {

              self::$conexao = null;

          }

      }   

  }

  use CONEXAO\Conexao;
  $conexao =  new Conexao;
  $conexao->abreConexao();
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? coloca a mensagem na pergunta.

Comment: 1) Se rodar o código, dá erro nessa linha? Se não, seu editor está mal configurado ou não suporta tal sintaxe; 2) Não faz sentido você executar um `return` no *catch* tendo o *finally*; 3) Faz menos sentido ainda você dar `return` dentro do construtor.

Comment: Então, fiz uma alteração no código e coloquei no final da pergunta. Eu criei uma função abreConexao() só pra isso. Sim: continua dando erro de servidor (500). Mas no console dá Request URL: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABNEAAABECAAAAACKI/xBAAAAAnRSTlMAAHaTzTgAAAn9SURBVHgB7J1Rktu8EYRbKSV/cBEeZfcA1COOh8fFAeyj8CLzqNh2dRnroTmFABYEar7UL8GDGUhc7rYagMjA... enorme

Comment: Qual é a sua versão do PHP? O `finally` só foi incluído na versão 5.5. Outra coisa, essa requisição que você cita é de uma imagem, não parece ter relação com o problema.

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.1

Comment: retiriei o finally e ainda continua dando ero 500. Código no final da pergunta

Comment: Vais ter de consultar os logs do servidor para perceber o erro. Sempre deu 500? Ou começou a dar com alterações recentes?

Comment: Precisa olhar  o log de erros do apache.

Comment: enviei  uma ultima correção no final da pergunta. Acho que o problema está na concatenação de variáveis na chamada ao PDO. cada parâmetro é limitado pro '', são 3 ao todo. mas quando quero colocar uma variável no lugar do parâmetro dá erro. Por favor. Dê uma olhada para mim como fiz no final da pergunta

Comment: pode ver o script rodando em http://www.funerariasaopedro.net.br/crud/Conexao

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta mudar a linha onde fazes a conexão, erro 500 pode ter muitas causas, mas acho que aquelas quebras de linha e usares as variáveis dentro de uma string com `'` em vez de `"` está a causar esse problema.

```
self::$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host={self::$host};dbname={self::$dbname}", self::$user, self::$password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

Classe:

```
<?php

  namespace CONEXAO;

  ini_set("display_errors",true);
  ini_set("display_startup_erros",true);
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);     

  use PDO; 

  class Conexao {

      private static $conexao;
      private static $host     = "localhost";    
      private static $dbname   = "dbname";
      private static $user     = "user";
      private static $password = "password";

      public function __construct() {

          try {

             self::$conexao = new PDO('mysql:
                                              host='.self::$host.';
                                              dbname='.self::$dbname, 
                                              self::$user, 
                                              self::$password
                                     );

          } catch (Exception $e) {

            self::$conexao = NULL;

            echo $e->getMessage();

          } 

      }

      public function abreConexao() {

          return self::$conexao;

      }


      public function fechaConexao () {

          if (self::$conexao != null) {

              self::$conexao = null;

          }

      }   

  }
```

Arquivo que chama a classe:

```
  use CONEXAO\Conexao;
  $conection =  new Conexao;
  $conexao = $conection->abreConexao();

  $str = "SELECT * FROM administradores";
  $query = $conexao->prepare($str);     
  $query->execute();
  $resultado = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
  print "<pre>";
  print_r( $resultado  );   
  print "</pre>";
```